# Is there a PHP function that will check to make sure fields are set in an array

Tags: php, arrays, find, key-value

Does php library have any function to check if all required fields are set in an array?  For example:

```
function required_fields($vals,$required_fields_names){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($required_fields_names); $i++){
        if(!array_key_exists($required_fields_names[$i],$vals)){
            return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there already a native PHP function/method that does this?

Comment: No. Although chances are this is a bit faster and more readable with a foreach.

Comment: Not really. On a side note a key can exist but it's value can be empty or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_difference` is the closest built-in function for this:

```
function required_fields($vals,$required_fields_names){
    $missing_fields = array_difference($required_fields_names, array_keys($vals));
    return empty($missing_fields);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NO, there is no native method.

But you can improve that code.

```
<?php 

function check_keys($keys,$array) {
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

# Test Zone 

$a = array('a' => 1,
           'b' => 2,
           'c' => 3);

$b = ['a','b','c'];
$c = ['a','b'];
$d = ['a','b','d'];


echo (int) check_keys($b,$a).'</br>'; # 1
echo (int) check_keys($c,$a).'</br>'; # 1
echo (int) check_keys($d,$a).'</br>'; # 0
?>
```